# Google Maps Api getting the title from the marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I push a marker to the array it plots the marker correctly and adds a title to the array too.

I know this works because when I console.log the `console.log(markersArray);` it returns the following. the title of the marker is `next door`.

[image]

The below is my marker click that opens up the info window, but when I console.log out the data which is called `mll` it doesn't have the title inside it.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(mll) {
    console.log(mll);
    var html= "<div style='color:#000;background-color:#fff;padding:5px;width:150px;'><p>"+mll+"</p></div>";
    iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:html});
    iw.open(map,marker);
});
```

[image]

How would I be able to get the `click` function to pull in the `title` when the array has it and has pushed it successfully?

Comment: If you look at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) for a Marker, a click event returns a MouseEvent as the argument to the handler function (your `mll`); you probably want to use `this` which should be a reference to the marker (so `this.getTitle()` will return the title).

Answer (score 1):

I remember doing something similar before. In my case, I used infoWindows with circle markers. Essentially, I had both in separate arrays. When I made the circle marker, I gave it a unique value, called place, which was basically it's count (the value of the *n*-th circle created, was *n*). On the event listener, I called the infoWindow from the other array based on the position of the current circle.

You can make an array `var titles = [];` to hold titles.
Each time you make a new marker, increment a `var count = 0;`, keeping track of how many markers you have. 
In your marker options, add `place: count`. When you need a specific title, you can call `titles[marker.place];`

```
  var infos = []; 
  var count = 0; 

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var lastWindow; 

  count++;
  var populationOptions = {
    //leaving out defaults
    place: count
  };

  var circle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
  lastCircle = circle; 

  var contentString = 'just a string...';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lon, data.lad)
  });

  infos.push(infowindow); 

  google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'mouseover', function() {
    if(lastWindow){
      lastWindow.close(); 
    }

    infos[circle.place].open(map);
    lastWindow = infos[circle.place]; 
  });
```