# Google Maps API missing data from array to markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Apologies in advance as this may seem a little complicated.

I have a Google Map Marker Array that my markers get added to called `markersArray`.

The details that get stored per marker are latitude, longitude, title, description.

Using the code below, it runs when a marker is clicked on my map

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(mll) {
                console.log(mll);
                console.log(markersArray);
                var html= "<div style='color:#000;background-color:#fff;padding:5px;width:150px;'><p></p></div>";
                iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:html});
                iw.open(map,marker);
            });
```

`mll` shows the log for the actual marker and `markersArray` just shows me the list of markers within the Array.

What I've noticed is that the data stored in `markersArray` is no being taken into the actual marker itself.

Is there a way of doing this?

If there isn't is there a way to use Javascript to find the `title` from the `markersArray` depending on the `latLng` values that you will see in the following image.

I screenshot what I receive when I run the Marker Click Function

[image]

Markers are added as follows using AngularJS:

```
$scope.createmarker = function () {
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': selectedItem.gps
    }, function (response, status) {
        geocode_results = new Array();
        geocode_results['status'] = status;

        top_location = response[0];
        var lat = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lat() * 1000000) / 1000000;
        var lng = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lng() * 1000000) / 1000000;
        geocode_results['lat'] = lat;
        geocode_results['lng'] = lng;
        geocode_results['l_type'] = top_location.geometry.location_type;
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: mapIcon,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            map: map,
            title: selectedItem.title
        });
        markersArray.push(marker);

        console.log(markersArray);
        console.log(marker);
    });
};
```

Comment: Where is the part where you add these properties? And where is the part where you add each marker to the array?

Comment: How do you store markers and their details into `markersArray`?

Comment: I have added how markers are added to the array

Comment: I see no description added to the marker but anyway... Did you try to log `selectedItem.title`? Do you really have something in there?

Comment: @MrUpsidown when I look at `markersArray` it does show that there is a title there. In the OP image check out the array at line `builder.js?v=1:94`

Comment: What is purpose of `geocode_results` array? You are creating that array for each marker.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I replaced `selectedItem.title` with `"Test"` it still did not work. The marker click shows the same info from `builder.js?v=1:94`

Comment: What do you meand by *the data stored in markersArray is no being taken into the actual marker itself.* Did you read what user geocodezip wrote as a comment to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461249/google-maps-api-getting-the-title-from-the-marker)? It seems to me that you are looking for title at the wrong place. Variable `mll` has no property `title` but `marker` has.

Comment: @AntoJurković thank you! I think you have just sussed it out! I was using `mll` instead of looking through the `marker` I will buy you a pint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `title` instead of `mll`

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(title) {
                console.log(mll);
                console.log(markersArray);
                var html= "<div style='color:#000;background-color:#fff;padding:5px;width:150px;'><p></p></div>";
                iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:html});
                iw.open(map,marker);
            });
```